# Scene builder GUI components do not look the same when I run the project from IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, scenebuilder, gluon, jfoenix

I am using Scene Builder, IntelliJ and some UI libraries (jfoenix, gluon-charm-glisten, fontawesomefx) to build a JavaFX desktop application, what I am doing is building the scene in the scene builder then saving the .fxml file to my project's directory, in IntelliJ I have added the mentioned libraries above to the external libraries by going to the Project's Settings..etc.

This is what I have built with the Scene builder:

I used Gluon's AutocompleteTextField

[image]

and this what I got after I run the project from IntelliJ.

[image]

**Question: Why is this happening and what are the possible ways of fixing it or avoiding it happening again?**

Comment: Looks like the css file isn't added

Comment: Do you define the path to SceneBuilder explicitly in Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | JavaFX?